# Load images to server from mobile site

Tags: image, load, mobile-safari

I am developing a mobile site using asp.net and jquery. no plugin. just simple jquery.
I am using the

```
   <input type="file"/>
```

of HTML5.

So few questions to get the big picture:

**1**.Can i load files **without jquery plugin**, but only **simple jquery**? Just picking the file, send it using ajax and catch it on server side?

**2**. I have noticed the Request.Files attribute of the Request object. Will it get filled only with post of the whole page or can i get my files there using Ajax?

**3**.In case the answer in 2 is "No!", how do i exclude the files data on the server side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i have found:

JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inputFile').on('change', function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var name = file.name;
            var size = file.size;
            var type = file.type;

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(file.name, file)
            $.ajax({
                url: 'AjaxPage.aspx',
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

CS: (On ajax page to catch the files and manipulate them as you will)

```
   var files = Request.Files;
```

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div>
    <input type="file" id="inputFile" />
  </div>

</body>
```